# Duplicating in Edit mode and cancelling the action deletes duplicate

Tags: edit-mode, shortcut

was working just fine a couple minutes ago, duplicate faces in edit mode, release, and the duplicate remains layered on top of original, this allowed me to do other functions were i want to keep the exact location of the duplicate by releasing/cancelling the action.
im not sure what i did or what sort of odd shortkey i made by accident but it now undoes the duplicate when releasing the action, why does this happen?

Comment: It's hard without seeing your interface but maybe you accidentally enabled auto-merge which automatically merges vertices which are closer than a certain threshold. In edit mode you can toggle this with the last icon in the top right corner of the 3D viewport

Comment: im afraid not.. auto merge is disabled on my end